# pandas to_dict() losing timezone info

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a database (SQLite ) with datetimes that are known to be in UTC. I'm aware that SQLite doesn't store tzinfo, but it can at least ensure it's in UTC before I commit to the db, then I know when I read it (via `read_sql`), I can enforce the dates to be read as UTC using the `parse_dates` option.
I can then do as I need and convert the timezone to some input string using `tz_convert(<string>)`, and it can print to the screen with the correct values including new datetime with timezone, which shows it does convert and it should all be good.
Except when I then export to a dictionary via the `to_dict`, the tz modification appears lost, and I'm back to UTC.
The only other thing I can think to do is some dictionary comprehension to convert every date in the dictionary, which does seem onerous. Even though the data set will be small (only around 500-600 entries) so processing time isn't really that much of a factor, I still want an elegant solution.

```
def get_data(start_date, end_date, tz):
  result=db.query(
    TABLE
  ).filter(
    TABLE.start>=start_date,
    TABLE.start<=end_date,
  )

  df = pd.read_sql(result.statement, engine, parse_dates={"start":{"utc":True}, "end":{"utc":True}})

  df.set_index("start", drop=False, inplace=True)
  df.index  = df["start"].index.tz_convert(pytz.timezone(tz))

  return df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

printing df before the return statement shows modified dates corrected adjusted to the timezone. But this appears lost when applying the to_dict (and to_json for that matter) methods.

Comment: could you provide a code snippet / output data with the unexpected result?

Comment: It's probably not necessary anymore, as I have an ok work around, which was to  parse dates as utc, then while sorting that returned data into the required structure, I just went ahead and modified the date while there. But I'll add it to the question anyway

Comment: tz information should not be lost by `to_dict()`. At least, I cannot reproduce this behavior. By the way, you don't need to use a `pytz` timezone for `tz_convert()` - you can simply pass a string, e.g. 'US/Eastern'.

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes. I had just realised that myself. But I do definitely lose the tz change, and I can't explain why. Is there something in the method I used that's different to yours? I can print the change to the console before I perform the `to_dict` and it shows it made the change, but when I print the returned dict object, it's back to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a Python/pandas version issue? `to_dict()` keeps tz info as it should on my machine (Win10, Python 3.8.3, pandas 1.0.3):

```
import pandas as pd
# pd.__version__
# '1.0.3'

# example series:
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-07', freq='H'))
# 0     2020-01-01 00:00:00
# 1     2020-01-01 01:00:00
# 2     2020-01-01 02:00:00
# 3     2020-01-01 03:00:00
# ...
# 144   2020-01-07 00:00:00

# localize to UTC:
s = s.dt.tz_localize('UTC')
# 0     2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
# ...
# 144   2020-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
# Length: 145, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

# convert to US/Eastern:
s = s.dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
# 0     2019-12-31 19:00:00-05:00
# ...
# 144   2020-01-06 19:00:00-05:00
# Length: 145, dtype: datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]

# to dict:
d = s.to_dict()
# {0: Timestamp('2019-12-31 19:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern'),
#  1: Timestamp('2019-12-31 20:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern'),
#  2: Timestamp('2019-12-31 21:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern'),
#  3: Timestamp('2019-12-31 22:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern'),
#  ...
#  144: Timestamp('2020-01-06 19:00:00-0500', tz='US/Eastern')}
```

Comment: Yeah, i get the same result when I run it as above, but the same functionality doesn't stay when you replace the Series with the read_sql. I've come across the same 'solution' before, but it doesn't seem to stick when you get the data from a database rather than from a specially data set.

Comment: @Fonty: Hm, what is the dtype of the datetime column in the df returned by pandas.read_sql? Is it correctly casted to datetime64[ns, tz]? Maybe you can find the issue on [github/pandas-dev](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)?

Comment: It's returned as a datetime, but without the tz unless I use the `parse_dates` option to force it to be UTC. But it does then print out as you suggest in full datetime format.